# How do i match a a key word from a split string to a text file - Python

Tags: unix

I want to take the user's input, splitinto separate words match a specific key word in input back to a text file, when key word is matched in the text file it prints the line it is on..

Comment: You need to `enumerate` your text file and then save the word and the index, a dictionary would work for this

Comment: how do we determine which word is the keyword after the user's input is split into separate words?

Comment: The keywords would be in the solutions file along with the line containing the actual solution if this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your line of code: "if problem in line:" with:

```
if len(list(set(problem) & set(line.split())))>0:
```

add explanation as requested:
1) line.split() will turn a line of text into a new list.
2) set(list1) & set(list2) will produce an intersection of two lists.
3) if length of intersection from two lists is 0, it means: nothing is common in two list.

hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent solution.

Comment: @Windchill thanks a lot for the solution, if you wouldn't mind do you think you could explain to me how this code works and why you have used what you have used? :)

Comment: @Carlos_Ade , kindly please let me know my explanation is sufficient enough.

Comment: @Windchill Perfect! Thanks a lot for the support :D